# Will errors be caught by try catch block when I don't have await in front of my asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

Will the following JavaScript try catch block still catch errors if I don't have await in front of my asynchronous function as shown below?

```
async () => {
   try {
      someAsynchronouseFunction();
   } catch (err) {
      // will errors from my asynchronous function still be caught here?
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it? What happened? I would guess not, because without `await` you'll just be calling a function that returns a promise and the error would go through to any `catch` callback rather than the caller.

Comment: Should `someAsynchronouseFunction` really be async, it will simply return an unresolved promise (which you don't even store), and code will continue. The async function may then at a later time execute, throw an error, and that error will be caught nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they won't, because `someAsynchronouseFunction();` will only resolve to a rejected `Promise`, and a rejected `Promise` alone doesn't result in an error, even in a `try` block. Instead, you would just see `Uncaught (in promise) Error: err!` in console:

```js
async function someAsynchronouseFunction() {
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  console.log('end of someAsynchronouseFunction, about to throw');
  throw new Error('err!');
}

const foo = async () => {
   try {
      someAsynchronouseFunction();
   } catch (err) {
     console.log('error found: ' + err);
   }
   console.log('end of foo');
}

foo();
```